# Detect time of onsets via Librosa

Tags: python, python-3.x, librosa

I am writing a Python script that will detect onsets(a new note), in a song and the relative time in seconds to the onset values. I know how to detect an onset, using the following code...

```
import numpy as np
import librosa.display 

y, sr = librosa.load("Audio\sweet_child_intro.wav")       

onset_envelope = librosa.onset.onset_strength(y, sr)
onsets = librosa.onset.onset_detect(onset_envelope=onset_envelope)
```

I don't know if there is a way on how to get the time of the onsets? I have looked at quite a few lectures, as well as forums and have not found anyone to discuss this topic - so if someone could please advise me on how to do this that'd be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
onset_times = librosa.frames_to_time(onsets)
print(onset_times)
```